# Google sheet : Imported content is empty (#N/A) How to solve this problem?

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a google sheet using price data from a website :

I would like to get the "Current price" of the material
https://theunderminejournal.com/#eu/ravencrest/item/124669

I tried to use the formula :  `=IMPORTXML("https://theunderminejournal.com/#eu/ravencrest/item/124669","/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/table/tr[3]/td/span/text()")`

But I overcome the following error message : Imported content is empty

I wonder if someone could help me with that ? : //

Comment: There is no possibility by importxml or importhtml. The site needs JavaScript to be enabled (`Please enable JavaScript to use this site.`) to give informations and the data is retrieved by an asynchronous method (`<script src="https://wow.zamimg.com/widgets/power.js" async></script>`)..

Comment: See here to test your site ... https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun

Comment: @MikeSteelson thanks a lot for your answer, would it work if I try to use =IMPORTJSON ?

Comment: Unfortunately not in your case, because the source of the web page did not contain any json even encapsulated by a script. May be with help of Selenium. Or via excel by simulating chrome, capturing what is readable and pasting it inside excel.